# type 'Future<File>' is not a subtype of type 'File'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

**Important:** I have searched a lot but did not find any solution that I can understand.
I am using photo manager to show images and then after selecting an image I want to navigate to the next screen and show that image there (later I want to upload that image to firebase storage).

So the type of File I am getting from the photo_manager package is **Future < File >** and I am receiving **File** from the second screen.

How can I convert future to file?

**First Screen:**

```
IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward, color: primaryColor),
        onPressed: () {
          Get.to(PostDetail(
            imgFile:
                _controller.mediaList[_controller.selectedImageIndex].file,
          ));
        },
      ),
```

**Second Screen:**
On the second screen, I'm getting File.

```
final File imgFile;
  const PostDetail({this.imgFile});
```

**Source Code:**: [Add Post Page](https://github.com/iahmadamin/instagram/blob/backend/lib/ui/pages/AddPost/post_detail_page.dart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as described in [photo_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/photo_manager#assetentity) docs, you need to get the file from the AssetEntity list before moving to the next page.

So on button pressed to go to next page get the file and then pass it to the Page

Below code should work:

```
 IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward, color: primaryColor),
            onPressed: () async {
              File file = await _controller.mediaList[_controller.selectedImageIndex].file; // image file
              Get.to(PostDetail(
                imgFile: file,
              ));
            },
          ),
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved me spending one more day on this bug, BTW this was easy but sometimes we got distracted so much that we even forget that how easy it is to solve,

Comment: Haha ya, it happens :)

Answer (score 1):

`File` and `Future<File>` are 2 different things. the `File` is a variable that its value is in the present. but `Future<File>` as its name suggests, its value exist in the Future which means its value takes some time to reach you.

for example, if you send a request to a webserver, the response takes some time to reach you. so, in that case the response is a Future.

in your case the image you are trying to get is supplied in a way that it takes time. to get the `File` from `Future<File>` you have to wait. So before sending the file to this Screen, use an async and wait to turn the `Future<File>` to `File`. (i dont know how you get the file)

for example,

```
File myFile = await getFileorWhaterver();
```

Comment: To learn about how future works in flutter: https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

Comment: didn't knew stack overflow hides things inside `<>`

Answer (score 1):

Your `_controller.mediaList[_controller.selectedImageIndex].file` is a `Future<File>` means that the value of the `File` is promised to be returned sometimes **in the future**. This usually because you are doing a network call asynchronously to get the data from API.

In order to convert it to `File`, you need to await till the moment that value is available. However you cannot do an `async/await` within the UI, that's why Flutter provide a widget named `FutureBuilder` to wait for a certain `Future` value, then let you use that value in the UI.

In your case, you can do this:

```dart
FutureBuilder(
  future: _controller.mediaList[_controller.selectedImageIndex].file,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward, color: primaryColor),
      onPressed: () {
        if (snapshot.hasData)
          Get.to(PostDetail(imgFile: snapshot.data));
      },
    );
  })
```